# Remove extra module nesting in import

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

How can I remove the need for `default` when accessing `config.default.database.cluster`?

config/env/development.js:

```
const config = {
    database: {
        cluster: '...',
        password: '',
        bucket: '...'
    }
}

export default config;
```

config/env/index.js:

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(`./${env}.js`);

export default config;
```

config/db.js:

```
import config from './env';

const cluster = new couchbase.Cluster(config.default.database.cluster);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `require` which returns a *module object with a `default` property*. Instead, explicitly access the `default` property when you `require`:

```
const config = require(`./${env}.js`).default;
```

This will save the default export of `development.js` to `config` so when you export `config`, the default export *is already exported*. That will get rid of the `default` when accessing.